# Were there any spacefaring Ewoks?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, ewoks

In the expanded universe do any Ewoks ever leave the forest moon?

Comment: Hell, I wish not! Those little rodents have destroyed the empire! :D

Comment: Why am I visualizing a trebuchet built with their gigantic logs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. X-Wing book series (second half by Aaron Allston) had a biologically enhanced Ewok [Kolot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolot) who flew with the <strike>Rogue</strike>Wraith Squadron.

Amusingly, before meeting Kolot, **everyone in the galaxy (as per Lucas's canon) was 100% sure that Ewoks aren't intelligent enough to pilot a starfighter**.

So, Wedge Antilles made up a fictional Wraith pilot Kettch, who became a legend and then a Ewok doll fighter pilot dummy that flew with Wedge. And then they acquired the acquaintance of Kolot.

Comment: You might mention Kolot's inspiration, [Kettch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kettch), even though he was a hoax.

Comment: @Kevin - um... to doll or not to doll.... sure... Yub  Yub!!

Comment: I read the X-Wing series many years ago but I don't remember this. I must have blocked it out of my mind.

Comment: @Null Kettch was in the later X-wing books (6? 7?), IIRC, Kolot was first introduced as sort of a teaser at the last book I read (9?). So it's possible you just didn't read far enough.

Comment: @Kevin I read them all. I'm pretty sure I blocked this out of my head, and I'm a little annoyed at this question for reminding me.

Comment: @Null - I donno. I found this kinda endearing. Yub-Yub!

Comment: Some more detail: the running prank that was Kettch first appeared in *Wraith Squadron*, an invention of Wes Janson (not Wedge; he was the first victim of the prank). The joke escalated and Kettch became a cover identity (a pilot with the Hawk-bat pirates) in *Iron Fist*. And a real Ewok pilot, Kolot, was discovered (by one person, not by all of the Wraiths) in *Solo Command*.

Answer (score 25):

Although Ewoks are a rare sight in the galaxy, several HAVE left Endor according to Legends canon. Chief among these are:

- [**Tarfang**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarfang) - a criminal & smuggler, Tarfang was encountered by the Solo family during the Yuuzhan Vong War. He often used his cuddly appearance to deceive others.
- [**Kolot**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolot) - a cyborg creation of [Project Chubar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Chubar), Kolot eventually became co-pilot in a shuttle business on Corellia
- [**Treek**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Treek) - a mercenary who escaped the Endor system by hijacking a crashed freighter, Treek became somewhat famous during the [First Galactic War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_War)
- [**Unidentified Jedi**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Ewok_Jedi) - in the days of the Yuuzhan Vong War, at least one Ewok had trained as a Jedi, presumably at Luke's Praxeum on Yavin IV.
- [**Megawok**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Megawok) - the "Megawok" was a giant (presumably mutant) Ewok which was sighted around the galaxy in the days of the Galactic Civil War. How it got so big or left Endor is unknown.
- [Unidentified Cantina Patron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tall_Tales) - an unidentified Ewok was present at a cantina altercation involving Han Solo in the days of the New Republic
- [Unidentified Bounty Hunter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fett_Club) - according to unsubstantiated rumors, an Ewok was among the bounty hunters who responded to Count Dooku's invitation on Coruscant.

Comment: LOL, I got a good laugh at [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fett_Club?file=FettClubpic--Ewok.jpg). +1. The rest I need to scrub from my mind again.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes.

- [Tarfang](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarfang) is a smuggler and copilot who appears in the (Legends) Dark Nest trilogy.
- [Treek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Treek) travels with the player in the video game *Star Wars The Old Republic*.

Answer (score 0):

There are Ewoks (Indirectly mentioned only) in 'The Face of Evil' (a short story by Landry Q Walker) as being present in Maz Kanata's castle. So I guess this is Cannon. 
They are also (Indirectly mentioned) in the novel Aftermath; also Cannon.